# Get data from a metatrader 4 alert

Tags: mql4, mt4

I use an indicator that generates alerts like: eur / USD Buy 1.122323, TP 1.131232, SL 1.114354, my question is how in an EA to read this data to execute the buy order.

Comment: There is no built in way using MQL4 commands. You could possibly read the log file as alerts would usually be written to the experts log, it is not always updated immediately however.

Answer (score -1):

cheat engine memory

```
 using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;
    using Telegram.Bot;
    
    namespace ConsoleApp45
    {
        class Program
        {
            const int PROCESS_WM_READ = 0x0010;
    
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);
    
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(int hProcess,
              int lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, ref int lpNumberOfBytesRead);
    
            public static void Main()
            {
                string ipek = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("terminal")[0];
                    IntPtr processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_WM_READ, false, process.Id);
    
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
    
                    //02DD12A4 cheat engine den alınan değer 0x02DD12A4 bu şekilde girilir.
                    ReadProcessMemory((int)processHandle, 0x02DD12A4, buffer, buffer.Length, ref bytesRead);
    
                    string yasin = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more on the example here to have a better understanding.

Comment: This is not MQL4 and therefore does not answer the question